# Xamarin PCL and sqlite.net

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library, executequery

I would have the need, in a pcl Xamarin, to pass to a function a type, which is then used to perform a query. 
The code that I tried to use is this:

```
public object sqlLeggi(string sql, Type myType){
 SQLiteCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand(sql);
 var results = cmd.ExecuteQuery< myType > ();
[..]
}
```

but it does not work, give me this error:

```
The type or namespace 'myType' could not be found.
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do such a thing?

Thank you very much

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with portable class libraries, xamarin, monotouch, executequery or sqlite. This is just a confusion between a `Type` object and a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myType` in the two statements play very different roles:

```
public object sqlLeggi(string sql, Type myType){
```

Here, `myType` is a `Type` object, referencing an instance of the [Type class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var results = cmd.ExecuteQuery< myType > ();
```

Here, `myType` is a *Type identifier*, which is a syntactic construct referring to a specific type, one that would actually be *named* `myType` in this case.

Now, there is usually two ways to handle this specific problem:

1. Look at the object type in `cmd` and see if there is an overload or alternative method to `ExecuteQuery` that takes a `Type` object parameter instead
2. Make your method generic so that you don't have a `Type` object to begin with.

The first case would presumably be written in this way:

```
var results = cmd.ExecuteQuery(myType);
```

The second like this:

```
public myType sqlLeggi<myType>(string sql{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand(sql);
    var results = cmd.ExecuteQuery< myType > ();
    [..]
}
```

Note that:

1. I made the method return `myType` instead of `object`
2. `myType` is now specified as a generic parameter to the method: `sqlLeggi<myType>`

Naming convention in this case would dictate that your generic type parameter be named `T` or something beginning with `T` so here is my advice:

```
public T sqlLeggi<T>(string sql{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = DB.CreateCommand(sql);
    var results = cmd.ExecuteQuery<T>();
    [..]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I would have answered it. I wish I could upvote more than once.